# Whenever I try to install geany in Ubuntu 18.04, there is this following issue. How should I solve it?

Tags: command-line

This error is coming up saying, *unable to fetch some archives*

The error is:

```
ss@ss-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Desktop
ss@ss-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install geany
[sudo] password for ss: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  geany-common
Suggested packages:
  libvte9 doc-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  geany geany-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,849 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 geany-common all 1.32-2 [1,816 kB]


Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 geany amd64 1.32-2
  File has unexpected size (236 != 1032704). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:7214e34293489b87f7efd1fd683dd46a388100c235301b2ddced727bd8abf4c9
   - SHA1:1ee3d16429a37b175e2603076dae3750b5b3c5da [weak]
   - MD5Sum:99d1f520e00cbbedb58fefc691159672 [weak]
   - Filesize:1032704 [weak]

Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 geany-common all 1.32-2
  File has unexpected size (236 != 1816396). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:0862b006449d872f31daae1c8ffac9cf37c311bed388e1c8866733eb6352e215
   - SHA1:c80f7bf0b98ed06828ae0822beb909b4dc3f8f02 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:cb31283bf908928bf83a9ad6e1973cd7 [weak]
   - Filesize:1816396 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geany/geany-common_1.32-2_all.deb  File has unexpected size (236 != 1816396). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:0862b006449d872f31daae1c8ffac9cf37c311bed388e1c8866733eb6352e215
    - SHA1:c80f7bf0b98ed06828ae0822beb909b4dc3f8f02 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:cb31283bf908928bf83a9ad6e1973cd7 [weak]
    - Filesize:1816396 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geany/geany_1.32-2_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (236 != 1032704). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:7214e34293489b87f7efd1fd683dd46a388100c235301b2ddced727bd8abf4c9
    - SHA1:1ee3d16429a37b175e2603076dae3750b5b3c5da [weak]
    - MD5Sum:99d1f520e00cbbedb58fefc691159672 [weak]
    - Filesize:1032704 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: I am a new Linux user and hence totally a novice in managing command prompt errors. Please help.

Comment: Please don't upload images of text. Copy and paste the text in your question and format the text as code using the icon above the question edit box.

Comment: I notice two things: "Mirror sync in progress?" which tells me the mirror site may have been busy at the time; and all downloaded files have an unexpected length of 236 bytes. If you looked inside those files, you would probably see something like "file not available - please retry later". (If you are curious, look up a file called `geany-`something in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and do a `less [filename]` to see what the actual error message is.) I think you should try it again in half an hour or so.

Comment: In addition to what Jos suggested about trying again later, please pay attention to `0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.` The `13 not upgraded` could be significant. Please run `sudo apt-get update` and if that is satisfactory, run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If there is anything in the latter output you don't understand, press `n` at the `[Y/n]` prompt and then post the **entire** output of both commands here.